# CSS floated divs with margin between them (example img in description)

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is probably a classic problem but I can't seem to figure out the solution. I have a number of divs that need to wrap in a container. That's pretty simple by adding `float: left` and a fixed width.

But, how do I get margin between them without having margin on the right-hand card. These divs are generated dynamically so I can't use a different class on the second div in order to target it.

Any ideas?

[image: float trickiness]

Comment: I hate to say it, but really looks like it might be case for <table> :)

Answer (score 1):

if I wanted to do this strictly in CSS without scripting or backend intervention, I might use the `nth-child` property:

**CSS**

```
.card { width: 60px; height: 100px; background-color: #ededed; border: 1px solid #999; }
.card:nth-child(even) { float: left; }
.card:nth-child(odd) { float: right; }
#container { width: 130px; }
#header { width: 100%; color: #fff; background-color: #000; margin-bottom: 3px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div class="card">0</div>
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
    <div class="card">4</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bpMCB/

Of course, you'd have to play around with the dimensions to suit what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to try:

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

Another way I came up with, you need to have space for a containing div:

```
<style>
    #container {
        background: white;
        width: 510px;
        height: 610px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #container2
    {
        width: 520px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .card {
        background: grey;
        margin: 5px;
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you might not want to go this route, as it effectively makes it a table.. :-\  There's some interesting discussion on there though.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I sometimes use is to have add an additional wider div to allow the float and then hide any overlap on the top level div. Difficult to explain without an example - [so here is one](http://jsfiddle.net/6dN5f/)

The .inner div contains the float because it's 10px wider, and the .outer div crops those 10px.

HTH :)